# How To Close Locked InputStream?

Tags: java, inputstream, jtextfield

I'm currently working on sending input from jtextfield component to other linux machine by jsch library. Commands goes well but the program doesn't close properly.

The shell thread waits and is never closed. Below is the status of the thread.

```
"Shell for 192.168.0.101" #29 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000165cf000 nid=0x2df4 in Object.wait() [0x000000001ce3e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x00000000c3c8c8e0> (a com.project.object.TextFieldStreamer)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
        at com.project.object.TextFieldStreamer.read(TextFieldStreamer.java:48)
        - locked <0x00000000c3c8c8e0> (a com.project.object.TextFieldStreamer)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:170)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSession.run(ChannelSession.java:245)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelShell.run(ChannelShell.java:34)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

It looks like waiting for input, but I want to close the program. 
I tried in.close(), but it doesn't work.
How can I close it?

```
public class TextFieldStreamer extends InputStream implements ActionListener
{
    public static final String TAG = "TextFieldStreamer";
    private JTextField         tf;
    private String             str = null;
    private int                pos = 0;

    public TextFieldStreamer(JTextField jtf)
    {
        tf = jtf;
    }

    // gets triggered everytime that "Enter" is pressed on the textfield
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        str = tf.getText() + "\n";
        pos = 0;
        tf.setText("");
        synchronized (this)
        {
            // maybe this should only notify() as multiple threads may
            // be waiting for input and they would now race for input
            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read()
    {
        // test if the available input has reached its end
        // and the EOS should be returned
        if (str != null && pos == str.length())
        {
            System.out.println("str ended up.");
            str = null;
            // this is supposed to return -1 on "end of stream"
            // but I'm having a hard time locating the constant
            return java.io.StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF;
        }
        Preferences.Log(TAG, "TextFieldStreamer.read(): " + "str: " + str);
        // no input available, block until more is available because that's
        // the behavior specified in the Javadocs
        while (str == null || pos >= str.length())
        {
            try
            {
                // according to the docs read() should block until new input is available
                synchronized (this)
                {
                    System.out.println("wait");
                    this.wait();
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // read an additional character, return it and increment the index
        return str.charAt(pos++);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think subclassing `InputStream` is a tad extreme. The only times I'd extend it is if I needed specific work done to the bytes before reading like decoding or decrypting for example. I think you'd have a better time rethinking this a bit, moving your text field logic to a different class, and using a built `InputStream`. Cool project though!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could solve the problem by not using `this` as locking object. Use a dedicated `Object lock = new Object()` to work with `synchronized`